# sql query for displaying start/end points with time interval

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have a table called vehicle_Summary and the data loks like:

```
A_Date                         vehicle_Name        Location_Name
2012-02-08 09:36:20.000        AA000AA               Denver
2012-03-08 09:36:20.000        AA000AA               Tokyo
2012-04-08 09:30:50.000        AA000AA               Melbourne
2012-12-08 09:36:20.000        AA000AA               Geneva
2012-22-08 00:00:00.000        AA000AA               NY 

2012-01-08 09:36:20.000        DPT011                Hobart
2012-03-08 09:36:20.000        DPT011                Tasmania
2012-04-08 09:30:50.000        DPT011                Java
2012-12-08 09:36:20.000        DPT011                Manila
2012-22-08 00:00:00.000        DPT011                Singapore
```

and i have vehicle_Info table as

```
vehicle_Name

DPT011
AA000AA
Z400
```

So first i search all vehicles from vehicle_Info table and
when i query b/w two time interval on vehicle_Summary
say 2012-02-08 04:44:44.444 and 2012-12-08 09:44:44.444

wt i expect is

```
vehicleName                     start_Point                   end_Point
AA000AA                         Denver                        Geneva
DPT011                          Tasmania                      Manila
```

im using MS Sql server 2k5 , i want this as query instead of performing the manual logic in C#. is this possible

Comment: What's the data type of your `A_Date` column, and what have you tried?

Comment: A_Date is date time , actually i have done from codebehind c# that is query through all vehicles and select each vehicle to search b/w time using (A_Date >= '2012-02-08 04:44:44.444') AND (A_Date <= '2012-12-08 09:44:44.444') from this i will be getting one record per vehicle, but nowhere i can show it as startpoint and endpoint in gridview for all vehicles

Answer (score 0):

Assuming A_Date as `Datetime`, you can use `Between` operator to get your result something like this:-

```
WHERE A_Date Between '1/20/2009' And '2/21/2009'
```

or try like this:-

```
WHERE startdate >= startdate AND enddate <=enddate
```

Comment: s datatype is datetime.. ok.. but how do i get to store startDate's and endDate's location per vehicle and keep adding row for next vehicle

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
  SELECT
    vehicle_name,
    MIN(A_Date) AS StartDate,
    MAX(A_Date) AS EndDate
  FROM vehicle_Summary
  WHERE A_Date BETWEEN '2012-08-02 04:44:44.444'
                   AND '2012-08-12 09:44:44.444'
  GROUP BY vehicle_name
)
SELECT 
  c.vehicle_name, 
  s.Location_name AS start_Point, 
  e.Location_name AS end_Point
FROM CTE AS c
INNER JOIN vehicle_summary s  ON s.vehicle_name = c.vehicle_name
                             AND s.A_Date       = c.StartDate 
INNER JOIN vehicle_summary e  ON e.vehicle_name = c.vehicle_name
                             AND e.A_Date       = c.EndDate;
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/68328/2)

This will give you:

```
| VEHICLE_NAME | START_POINT | END_POINT |
------------------------------------------
|      AA000AA |      Denver |    Geneva |
|       DPT011 |    Tasmania |    Manila |
```

---

### Update 1

You can also, `JOIN` the other table to get the vehicle name from there:

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
  SELECT
    i.vehicle_id,
    i.vehicle_name,
    MIN(s.A_Date) AS StartDate,
    MAX(s.A_Date) AS EndDate
  FROM vehicle_Summary AS s
  INNER JOIN vehicle_Info AS i ON s.vehicle_id = i.vehicle_id
  WHERE s.A_Date BETWEEN '2012-08-02 04:44:44.444'
                   AND '2012-08-12 09:44:44.444'
  GROUP BY i.vehicle_id,
           i.vehicle_name
)
SELECT 
  c.vehicle_name, 
  s.Location_name AS start_Point, 
  e.Location_name AS end_Point
FROM CTE AS c
INNER JOIN vehicle_summary s  ON s.vehicle_id = c.vehicle_id
                             AND s.A_Date     = c.StartDate
INNER JOIN vehicle_summary e  ON e.A_Date     = c.EndDate
                             AND e.vehicle_id = c.vehicle_id;
```

### [Updated SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7238b/5)

Comment: will give a try...and wil come back

Comment: @user1944477 - What do you mean? Do you mean the between from to? you can put it inside the *CTE* See the query above in my answer: `WHERE A_Date BETWEEN '2012-08-02 04:44:44.444'
                   AND '2012-08-12 09:44:44.444'`.

Comment: nice man..ur right .. but how about the other table (vehicle_Info) from where i pull vehicle name and supply it to vehicle_summary for searching..is it possible...

Comment: @user1944477 - Yes, you can Join that table, please post the two tables' structures or at least the structure of the other table and some sample data from it.

Comment: @user1944477 OK, I updated my answer, see my edit. But this is just a guessing, you might need to change the columns names.